# My button stays on high if I press it once, what did I do wrong?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, lcd, piezo

If I press my button once, I get characters on all of the 32 character places and I get an infinite tone with my piezo. Can someone help me with this?

[image: Arduino circuit]

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int buttonPin = A0;
int buttonState = 0;
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
byte run1c[8] = {
  B00000,
  B01100,
  B01100,
  B00000,
  B01110,
  B11100,
  B01110,
  B10010,
};

byte run2c[8] = {
  B00000,
  B01100,
  B01100,
  B00000,
  B11100,
  B01110,
  B11100,
  B10010,
};

byte jumpc[8] = {
  B01100,
  B01100,
  B00000,
  B11110,
  B01101,
  B11111,
  B10000,
  B00000,
};

byte jumpLowerc[8] = {
  B01110,
  B11100,
  B01110,
  B10000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
};

byte groundc[8] = {
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
};

byte rightGroundc[8] = {
  B00011,
  B00011,
  B00011,
  B00011,
  B00011,
  B00011,
  B00011,
  B00011,
};

byte leftGroundc[8] = {
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
  B11100,
};

void setup() {
  lcd.createChar(0, run1c);
  lcd.createChar(1, run2c);
  lcd.createChar(2, jumpc);
  lcd.createChar(3, jumpLowerc);
  lcd.createChar(4, groundc);
  lcd.createChar(5, rightGroundc);
  lcd.createChar(6, leftGroundc);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    tone(8, 400);
    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.write(byte(2));
    digitalWrite(buttonState, LOW);
  } else {
    lcd.setCursor(1,1);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
  }
}
```

Comment: digitalWrite(buttonState, LOW);  That line is writing either pin 0 or pin 1 low.   Did you mean to just set buttonState = LOW;

Comment: @Delta_G yes, I thought that would fix the problem, so i just have to write: buttonState = LOW;

Comment: You shouldn't have to write that at all.  It should set buttonState from the digitalRead at the top of loop right before it compares it.  But either way, trying to digitalWrite with another pins state as the pin number is definitely not right.

Comment: @Delta_G And if I move that white wire, connected to A0, to pin number 13, and change that in the code. Will that make a difference?

Comment: Sure, it will make it so that the code you have is reading the wrong pin.  If you change the pin number in the code as well then you're in the same boat.  Why don't you try an active LOW arrangement for the button like I described in my answer below.

Comment: @Delta_G Okay, and the resistor? I wired that one based off the Genuino starter kit book

Comment: @Delta_G the resistor is direcly connected to ground, the blue wire is connected to another resistor, wich is connected to the lcd display

Comment: If you use the internal pull-up and wire for active low you don't need any resistor.

Comment: Also take note that you would normally use the two diagonal pins on the button.  Two sets are normally close and two sets are normally open.  Or try rotating the button 90 degrees.

Comment: @Delta_G unfortunately i cant rotate the button, it just would not fit into the breadboard at that moment. And with wire for active low, do i just have to replace the resistor with a normal wire, or am i not understanding you. (My English isn't that good sometimes)

Comment: I gave you good instructions in the answer below.  You tie one side of the button to ground and the other side to the pin.  There will be only two wires connected to the button.  One going to ground and the other to the pin.  So when the button is pressed, it connects the pin to ground.

Comment: @Delta_G It still gave me the same problem as before

Comment: Show the new wiring and the new code.

Comment: Where, in your program, do you ever tell it *not* to play the tone? You start a 400Hz tone on pin 8 but never stop it.

Comment: @Majenko I have added the noTone() in else{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from your drawing, you have both sides of your button tied to 5V.  The green wire on one side and the blue wire through the resistor on the other.  So yes, the button will always read HIGH.

Instead, remove the resistor, tie one side of the button to the pin and the other side to ground.  Use INPUT_PULLUP in your pinMode cal instead of just INPUT.  Now a pressed button will read LOW and not pressed will read HIGH, so you'll have to reverse your logic in your code.  But the wiring will be much nicer.

Comment: the blue wire is connected to the lcd display with a 220 ohm resistor, the 10k ohm resistor is connected to ground

Answer (score 0):

In your code you check the button state and if it is high you set the tone.

In the else section you do nothing with the tone.

Hence, once on, it will always stay on.